# Taylor series expotential function in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att, taylor-series

I am trying to implement expotential function algorithm in assembly according to this equation:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/4/5/9/4597c1e758b3aeb83adcb03d3f75d00e.png

My code in assembly:

```
.data
x:
    .space 8
result:
    .space 8
counter:
    .space 8
factorial:
    .space 8
n:
    .space 8
xn:
    .space 8
.text
.global expot
expot:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    flds    8(%ebp)     # wczytaj x
    fstps   x
    flds    12(%ebp)    # wczytaj precyzje
    fstps   n
    fldz    
    fstps   result
    fld1
    fstps   factorial
    fld1
    fstps   counter
    fld1
    fstps   xn

loop:
    flds    factorial
    flds    xn
    fdiv    %st(1)
    fldl    result
    fadd    %st(1), %st(0)
    fstps   result

    flds    counter
    fcom    n
je end

    flds    xn
    fmul    x
    fstps   xn

    fld1
    flds    counter
    fadd    %st(1)
    fstps   counter

    flds    counter
    flds    factorial
    fmul    %st(1)
    fstps   factorial
jmp loop

end:
leave
ret
```

My code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern float expot (float x, float n);

int main(void)
{
    float x = expot (1, 4);
    printf ("%f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that this function doesn't return anything. When I am debugging it with gdb I see that in second iteration, when it should calculate x^n, the result is -nan and then when it should calculate 2! it returns -nan again. I completly don't know what is wrong with this code.

Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: Why is `n` a `float` and not an `int`?

Comment: Because I was thinking that I should use float if I'm comparing it to another float value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FPU stack isn't endless. In your loop you push (fld) more values than you pop (fstp). So the stack becomes full and every new push produces a NaN.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that this produces errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not returning any value.

The [x86 `cdecl` calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) indicates:

> Integer values and memory addresses are returned in the EAX register, floating point values in the ST0 x87 register.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I accidentally deleted line flds result after end:. It didn't help, it's still didn't return anything, because of errors with -nan.

Comment: @user3448282 Well it's time to break out the debugger then. Step through your function, verifying values along the way.

Comment: I did it and in second iteration and when it should mul xn*x it returns -nan value.